wix - Uinstall from Apps & Features does not show the Maintenance dialog
I am using wix toolset v4 to build an MSI that is using the built-in dialog WixUI_InstallDir.
When i double click on the MSI installer to uninstall the program, it does open the Maintenance dialog with the corresponding actions Repair, Remove and Modify.
The problem is when i try to uninstall from under Apps & Features in windows 10, the Maintenance dialog does not show at all.
Any idea?

This is the standard behavior. From App and features, UILevel property set to basic which skips the UI Sequence. But, You can enable/disble the Modify/Repair/Remove button in App and features.

Is it possible to disable the "Uninstall" option under "Apps & Features" and keep only the "Modify" option which opens the Maintenance dialog?

You won't get maintenance dialog here as I mentioned UILevel is set to basic only. It means only required UI will be displayed. Other dialogs will be suppressed.
You can only provide direct option to modify/repair/remove button
